# Python regex not giving me any matches

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match numbers that have 5 digits using regex in python. This is my code:

```
 import re
 matchstring = "These are 10101 random numbers 34345."
 regex_string = r'(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)'
 all_matches = re.findall(matchstring, regex_string)
```

I have no idea why I get 0 matches when I should get 2. I've tried using this regex on 2 python validator sites and on both sites these work. Any idea why in my code I get an empty list?

Comment: that's uncanny how the "original" question asks about _5_ digits exactly as well...

Answer (score 4):

Function [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) accepts arguments in order: pattern, then string:

```
re.findall(regex_string, matchstring)
['10101', '34345']
```

Comment: reverse order: OP has the order wrong, not `findall`

Comment: I mean "in order reverse to proposed" :) However in different languages may be different order - so it's easy to perplex.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
matchstring = "These are 10101 random numbers 34345."
final_numbers = [i for i in re.findall("\d+", matchstring) if len(i) == 5]
```

Output:

```
['10101', '34345']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
matchstring = "These are 10101 random numbers 34345."
regex_string = r"\b\d{5}\b"
re.findall(regex_string , matchstring)
```

output:

```
['10101', '34345']
```

Comment: try with numbers in the end: `"These are 10101 random numbers 34345"`

Comment: you can also use `r"\b\d{5}\b"`.

Comment: yeah that is more like it.